# Routing Error uninitialized constant Forem::ForumsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, forem

I've just freshly installed Devise, followed by Forem.

As I load /forums/ in my browser, I get the following error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Forem::ForumsController
```

I am running CentOS 6, and without Forem, there is no issue.
How do I fix this error, the Full Trace doesn't really give much help.

I tried restarting apache, and also restarting the server itself, neither methods have come to any luck.

Comment: did you restart your server?

Comment: I tried that, along with restarting apache